# Select Ajax response objects to send a new request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, ajax

I have an AJAX request as follows:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'TypeState',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    state_name: name,
    city_type: type
  },
  success: function(response) {
    alert(response.message);
    data = response.data;
    $('.tr').remove();
    for (i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

      $("#table").append("<tr class='tr'> <td> " +
        response.data[i].user_name + " </td> <td> " +
        response.data[i].user_contact + " </td> <td> " +
        response.data[i].user_license + " </td> <td> " +
        response.data[i].user_email + " </td> <td> " +
        response.data[i].state + " </td> <td> " +
        response.data[i].city);
    }
  },
  error: function(response) {
    alert("unable to pull up any users for the selected state");
  }
});
```

Depending upon the input data (`state_name` and `city_type`) I get lots of user object responses which I append to a table to display in my JSP page.

I wish give the client the ability to select a few of these user objects and send a new request. Can any one tell me how I could do that?

Comment: Store the `id` of the user as a `data` attribute on the `tr`, then attach a click handler to them which sends a new AJAX request with the `id` of the selected rows.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so i to make sure i understood correctly!! i require a variable to store multiple id's which are selected by the user, which i can send as a new request! but what im confused about is can a ajax request be done with array variables!

Comment: `can a ajax request be done with array variables` yes, absolutely.